# make animation continues on multi layers by using CAAnimation

Tags: ios, layer, caanimation

I'm creating a tutorial screen to let user understand what to do in the screen.

For example, I have `viewPlug` and `viewBulb`. First, `viewPlug` moves up until it collide `viewBulb`. After that `viewBulb` changes color to green to notify. After some seconds, `viewPlug` moves down and `viewBulb` changes to red immediately.

[image]

So far, I'm digging in `UIViewAnimation` and `UIViewKeyframeAnimation` but none of them give me full right to handle complex animation, duration, beginTime... Only `CAAnimation` can do exactly what I want in scenarios.

But I'm not sure if this is a best way to do in my case, or iOS supports other methods that easier/simpler to handle?

Here is my sample code.

```
 - (void)makeAnimations {
    // Group all animation into 1 transaction
    [CATransaction begin];

    // Create plug animation
    CABasicAnimation *animatePlug = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    animatePlug.beginTime = 0;
    animatePlug.byValue = @(-180);
    animatePlug.duration = 1.5;
    animatePlug.fillMode =kCAFillModeForwards;
    animatePlug.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    // Create unplug animation
    CABasicAnimation *animateUnplug = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    animateUnplug.beginTime = 4;
    animateUnplug.byValue = @100;
    animateUnplug.duration = 0.25;
    animateUnplug.fillMode =kCAFillModeForwards;
    animateUnplug.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    // Group all animation of view A
    CAAnimationGroup *animateGroupPosition = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animateGroupPosition.duration = 6;
    animateGroupPosition.animations = @[animatePlug, animateUnplug];
    animateGroupPosition.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [self.viewPlug.layer addAnimation:animateGroupPosition forKey:@"position"];

    // Create plug color animation
    CABasicAnimation *animateGreen = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    animateGreen.toValue = (__bridge id)([UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    animateGreen.beginTime = 1.5;
    animateGreen.duration = 0.5;
    animateGreen.fillMode =kCAFillModeForwards;
    // Create unplug color animation
    CABasicAnimation *animateRed = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    animateRed.toValue = (__bridge id)([UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    animateRed.beginTime = 4;
    animateRed.duration = 0.1;
    animateRed.fillMode =kCAFillModeForwards;
    // Group all animation of view B
    CAAnimationGroup *animateGroupColor = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animateGroupColor.duration = 6;
    animateGroupColor.animations = @[animateGreen, animateRed];
    animateGroupColor.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [self.viewBulb.layer addAnimation:animateGroupColor forKey:@"color"];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: Why does `UIViewAnimation` not work for you? You can set duration, delay etc.?

Comment: @michaelrccurtis There are many reason that UIViewAnimation is not suitable:
1. Manage in blocks: it's a pain if I want to include more animation, the complete block will extern over and over. The code won't clean and hard to maintain later.
2. It has duration, delay... but won't strong enough to handle, especially when an animation active while others are playing, or complex animation (combine shake, rotate, translate,.. together)

Comment: 1. Remember that you can create block variables, which means that you can easily create new animations from combinations of animation and completion blocks - there is absolutely no reasons for the complete block to be repeatedly executed. I don't really understand "the code won't clean" or hard to maintain comment. 2. UIView animation can handle all of these, but which you prefer to use is more of a personal preference.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis:  can you prefer me your sample code in `UIViewAnimation` ?

Comment: If there's something you specifically don't understand about animating with UIViewAnimation then I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Ah no, I understand `UIViewAnimation` and how to implement it in simple animation, but implementing it in my case quiet hard (comparing to `CAAnimation`). As you said, I think you have a solution for that using `UIViewAnimation` which might easier. If you can create a sample code, it will be great for comparing between 2 solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88964/discussion-between-nahung89-and-michaelrccurtis).